# Count break not working

Tags: java, infinite-loop, reverting

Any ideas as to why the `break` is not working here? I need to get it to work otherwise it just loops forever.

```
  int count = 0;           
  while (inputNumber != 0 )
  {
      int x = this.light.getDiameter();
      this.light.setDiameter(inputDiameter);
      changeColour();
      this.delay(100);
      this.light.setDiameter(x);
      changeColour();
      {
         count++;
      }
      if (count = inputNumber)
      {
         break;    // HERE: it was never reached. 
      }
   }
```

Comment: its ok i was being a moron should have read if(count ==inputNumber)

Answer (score 2):

I would change:

```
if (count = inputNumber)
```

to

```
if (count == inputNumber)
```

Comment: hi this was the solution, you are correct, i realised within 2 seconds of posting where i had gone wrong. Had i not realised though your answer would have been a massive help :D many thanks

Comment: Great, a plus would be appreciated.